# Printing out a binary tree of positive integers (visually)

Tags: algorithm, tree

I'm trying to create an algorithm that prints out a binary tree object that represents integers in the range 0 through 127.

**Example.**

If the only element in the tree was 0, then print this:

```
 /
0
```

**Example.**

If the only elements in the tree are 0 and 1, then print this:

```
 /\
0  1
```

**Example.**

If the only elements in the tree are 0, 1 and 2, then print this:

```
   /    \
  0      1
 / \   
0   1
```

**Example.**

If the elements in the tree are 0, 1, ..., 8, then print this:

```
      /         \
     0           1
   /   \       /   \
  0     1     0     1
 / \   / \   / \   / \
0   1 0   1 0   1 0   1
```

**Etcetera!**

For starters,

- Can anyone think of an algorithm to print an entire tree of numbers 0 through 127?
- If a given tree's largest number has n significant bits (and thus nodes), how many characters will the bottom of the tree take up, including the padding on the right of the bottom row? That's something I need to figure out because right now I'm trying to make an HTML table that will have 1 character per cell and be able to hold all the characters of a tree.
- Do you think that what I'm trying to do, printing the tree, is suicide? Since I'm trying to incorporate this into a website, should I start getting familiar with a JavaScript graphics package and find an alternative way of drawing up a tree from the user inputting integers? Any ideas?

Comment: The data structure you're showing seems more like a base 2 trie, also known as radix tree or prefix tree.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? What are your thoughts on how you'd go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt on the drawing (Python 2/3).

```
def go (n, k):
    m = (1 << (n + 1)) - 1
    s = " " * m + " /" + " " * (2 * m - 1) + "\\ " + " " * m
    print (" ".join ([s] * k))
    t = " " * m + "0 " + " " * (2 * m - 1) + " 1"  + " " * m
    print (" ".join ([t] * k))
    if n > 0:
        go (n - 1, k << 1)

go (0, 1)
go (1, 1)
go (2, 1)
go (3, 1)
```

The trees are:

For 0..1:

```
  / \  
 0   1
```

For 0..3:

```
    /     \    
   0       1   
  / \     / \  
 0   1   0   1
```

For 0..7:

```
        /             \        
       0               1       
    /     \         /     \    
   0       1       0       1   
  / \     / \     / \     / \  
 0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

For 0..15:

```
                /                             \                
               0                               1               
        /             \                 /             \        
       0               1               0               1       
    /     \         /     \         /     \         /     \    
   0       1       0       1       0       1       0       1   
  / \     / \     / \     / \     / \     / \     / \     / \  
 0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

Note that each line of numbers is evenly spaced, so it takes more width than your sketch.

For numbers 0..127, and with 128 digits and 4 characters per digit on the last line, its width is 512 characters, maybe minus a few spaces at the end. I doubt a 512-column table is a good thing do display, so perhaps that's not quite a solution for your problem. Still, it shows an estimate of what you will get.